# content of microcache.log file in vps

Tags: vps

My VPS shutdown because the HDD is filling up and I realized that the microcache.log file is becoming 12GB after I delete it. The content of microcache.log file is:

23.88.110.68 - - [12/Jun/2014:16:09:45 -0400] "GET http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=2168123&position=below HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "battercar.com/?p=436" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_4_11; en) AppleWebKit/528.4+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0dp1 Safari/526.11.2" nocache:

173.208.213.94 - - [12/Jun/2014:16:09:45 -0400] "GET ib.adnxs.com/tt?id=2962937 HTTP/1.0" 502 568 "http://www.existeducation.com/tag/tap/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.202.0 Safari/532.0" nocache:

(continues thousans of lines...)

How can I repair my VPS? I got tired to delete this file everyday.

VPS : Centos 6 with nginx

Answer (score 0):

Large LOG files should be deleted http://wikitechsolutions.com/2761/microcache-log-file-exceeds-my-vps-hdd